# Как сделать анимацию текста в HTML (с использованием JS/CSS если потребуется)

Tags: css, html5, анимация, текст

Увидел на этом сайте https://fatality.win/ анимацию логотипа, решил запилить такую же.
Осмотрел source и сам код, но ничего связанного с этой анимацией так и не нашёл. Сам текст в HTML вбит обычным h1, пробовал скопировать всю часть сайта с этим текстом, но анимация не отобразилась, значит использовался JS/CSS, однако я так и не смог выяснить что именно и как.
Помогите создать подобную анимацию, спасибо ♥[image: Синяя и красная подложки циклично перемещаются]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

анимация там через css
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`@keyframes uk-text-shadow-glitch{0%{text-shadow:none}25%{text-shadow:-2px -2px 0 #eb055a,2px 2px 0 #4632f0}50%{text-shadow:2px -2px 0 #eb055a,-2px 2px 0 #4632f0}75%{text-shadow:-2px 2px 0 #eb055a,2px -2px 0 #4632f0}100%{text-shadow:2px 2px 0 #eb055a,-2px -2px 0 #4632f0}}`

В консоли есть все

```css
h1 {
  animation: uk-text-shadow-glitch .65s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .9399999999999999) both infinite;
}

@keyframes uk-text-shadow-glitch {
  0% {
    text-shadow: none
  }
  25% {
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #eb055a, 2px 2px 0 #4632f0
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 2px -2px 0 #eb055a, -2px 2px 0 #4632f0
  }
  75% {
    text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #eb055a, 2px -2px 0 #4632f0
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #eb055a, -2px -2px 0 #4632f0
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> text </h1>
```